# need else arguments appear only once no matter how much string that are inputted in the loop

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input = " ";
    cout << "Do you wanted to input : " << endl << "a. String" << endl 
         << "b. Integer" << endl;
    while (input != "A" || input != "a" || input != "B" || input != "b")
    {
        cin >> setw(1) >> input;
        if (input == "A" || input == "a")
        {
            cout << "String" << endl; break;
        }
        else if (input == "B" || input == "b")
        {
            cout << "int" << endl; 
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please input only the given option." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

So, I'm currently using the code like the one i posted up there, my problem is that when i trigger the else arguments by inputting more than 1 string at a time like using the words 'how much' will result in else argument appear twice and if i input 'c d e' it will appear thrice when i only wanted it only appear once no matter how much string that are inputted. I know it probably had something to do with my loop that i missed but i just don't know what is it. Is there a resolve for this ? I'm so grateful for your kind help. Thank you very much

Comment: Perhaps you want to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead? Possibly with [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `while` loop, you could use a `do while` loop. Actually, you used a `break` after each successful branch. Thus, you could even use a `for (;;)` loop (an endless loop where condition is always true).

Demonstration:

```
$ cat >test-input.cc <<EOF
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string>
> 
> using namespace std;
> 
> int main()
> {
>   cout
>     << "Please, choose an option:" << endl
>     << "a. String" << endl
>     << "b. int" << endl;
>   for (;;) {
>     string input; getline(cin, input);
>     if (input == "a" || input == "A") {
>       cout << "String" << endl;
>       break;
>     }
>     if (input == "b" || input == "B") {
>       cout << "int" << endl;
>       break;
>     }
>     cout << "Please, choose one of the options." << endl;
>   }
>   cout << "Well done." << endl;
>   return 0;
> }
> EOF

$ g++ -std=c++11 -o test-input test-input.cc

$ ./test-input.exe 
Please, choose an option:
a. String
b. int
abc
Please, choose one of the options.

Please, choose one of the options.
a
String
Well done.

$ ./test-input.exe 
Please, choose an option:
a. String
b. int
b
int
Well done.

$
```

Notes:

1. I replaced `cin <<` by `getline()` as suggested by [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) (which I would prefer also).
2. There is no `else` as each "successful" `if` ends with a `break` (and thus following statements are not reached in this case). This you can imagine like an "implicit `else`".